# How do I customize keycloak AccountPages?

Tags: java, single-sign-on, keycloak, keycloak-services

I develop a customize spi_keycloak.

And It deployed successfully. but for some perposes I want to edit (add/delete) pages in AccountPages.

So for show what I want change, see this picture, I want to edit items(content) and menu in left.

[image]

How do I build and deploy in my keycloak.

In other words, when I access the /auth/realms/abc/account page, I can see there is a sidebar menu on the left with options like: “Account”, “Password”, “Authenticator”, and so on. I would like to add a new item in that sidebar and be able to access through something like /auth/realms/abc/account/custom

Comment: It is my cuestion too. Do you find any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Keycloak 12](https://www.keycloak.org/2020/12/keycloak-1200-released.html) was released recently and allows you to write custom React code in the account console. This is the recommended way to go for newer keycloak versions. You can customise the new account console as shown in the [keycloak quickstarts](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/extend-account-console).

For older keycloak versions you can customise the account console by [adding a custom theme](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_themes).
You can use the [existing base template for inspiration](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/a92bf0c3be45d65233512bc6a155fd35e3193905/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/account/template.ftl).

Later edit:
To create your custom rest endpoint please see [keycloak rest extension example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/providers/rest).

This can be used for managing your [***extended*** keycloak data model using jpa entities](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_extensions_jpa). For an example see [keycloak avatar extension](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/keycloak-avatar-minio-extension).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. But this solutions is only front side(Client), and I need to backend side (java) to call my functions. @Paul

Comment: This can be done by adding your rest endpoint. Please take a look here: [keycloak example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/providers/rest), [keycloak avatar](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/keycloak-avatar-minio-extension) and [beer resource example - older example](https://github.com/dteleguin/beercloak).

You might find that the avatar extension is exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much. I use rest endpoint. So How do I show my custom form (*.ftl) in RealmResourceProvider? LIKE: form.createForm("test.ftl").

Comment: You don't use form.createForm. You create a new theme that *extends* the keycloak theme with your custom account theme. That theme should contain the form. Please take a look at the [avatar example theme](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/keycloak-avatar-minio-extension/blob/master/avatar-minio-extension-module/src/main/resources/theme/account-avatar/account/account.ftl#L77). Also, the keycloak documentation on theme should came in handy.